# Can someone explain to me what the transfer function is in this context. How does it affect the circuit?

Tags: current, operational-amplifier

The image below is an excerpt from the datasheet for Analog Devices AD8572 Op-amp. The schematic shown is for a precision current meter.

What is the monitor output transfer function? How does it affect the circuit?

[image]

Thanks
Tim

Comment: This is better fit for electronic stackexchange. It has nothing to do with Arduinos. You will probably get better answers there

Comment: "transfer function" is a term of art in "control theory". I'm not sure you really need to dig deep into an understanding of this to use a current sense opamp. But if you do, as chrisl says, ESE is a better place to ask. For this it's probably enough to understand that 2.49V at monitor output will represent 1 amp through r_sense and load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the monitor output transfer function?

A circuit transfer function is an equation that relates the input of the circuit to the output.

$$ H(s) = \frac{output(s)}{input(s)} $$

In this circuit, the input is the load current \$I_L\$, and the output is the monitor output voltage. So the transfer function equation is:

$$ \frac{V_{out}}{I_L} = R2\:\frac{R_{sense}}{R1} $$

> How does it affect the circuit?

It doesn't really affect the circuit, it's just a convenient way to describe the circuit. You can easily see from the equation what you can change to get any output voltage to input current ratio you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very helpful information. I thought it was more than coincidence that R2 and the transfer function are both 2.49.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add a two cents here if you are curious how does this formula come about.
Firstly, we need to realize, what is the input and output of our transfer function. As Ryan mentioned earlier - our input is current, which passes through LOAD, and output is voltage drop across resistor R2.
We will also take into account the basic principles of an operational amplifier and a field effect transistor.

1. Current does not flow into the inputs of the operational amplifier
2. The operational amplifier covered by negative feedback (its output through the field-effect transistor sets the voltage at the inverting input) tries to equalize the potentials of the inverting and non-inverting inputs.
3. The influence of the output current of the operational amplifier on the output voltage of the resistor R2 can be neglected (when using a field effect transistor)

Here and below, I will use the symbol Vin representing the input voltage, which is shown as V + in the picture.
We use 2nd Kirchhoff's law to obtain (Vin - V-) = I1 * R1 (1) and (Vin - V+) = Isense * Rsense (2).
Also we know that Vload = Iload * Rload (3).
From 1st Kirchhoff's law we obtain that Isense = Iload (4) and I2 = I1 (5)(remember, no current flows into the input of the op-amp)
Output voltage (monitor output) Vout = I2 * R2 (6)
And using our rule 2 we get V+ = V- (7)
Now we use equality (6), replace I2 with I1 from (5), and replace I1 from expression (1), then use (7) and (4).

Sorry for bad formula design, but i hope it would be useful for someone who wants to understand where AD's formula came from.